# Proof of #P-completeness of the number of simple paths in a simple graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

I have a simple non-directed graph and I am trying to find an algorithm to solve the number of simple paths that are possible. The problem is that I have seen in some forums that this problem is #P-Complete. Is there any proof of the #P-completeness of this problem? I need to find the proof of #P-Completeness or at least know how to deduce it myself in order to justify that there is no efficient algorithm for this problem.

Comment: See Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/MCC17/Papers/enumerate.pdf)

Comment: I can't see how Theorem 1 is related to paths. Isn't it Theorem 11? and even though it proves that the maximum number of simple graphs from s to t is a #P-complete problem, how can I extend it to the total number of simple paths in a graph?

Comment: It's problem 14.  I don't see a theorem 11.  I guess you're right in that it's concerned with the number of $s-t$ path and not the total number of paths, but I'd be surprised if it were possible to compute the total number of simple paths in polynomial time and not the number of paths between two specific vertices.   When I Googled the problem, I kept finding references to this paper that weren't publicly accessible, but then I found this copy someone had posted, and sent you the link.  I haven't read the paper.

Comment: Sorry, by Theorem 11 I referred to the proof of hardness of problem 11 on the list of #P-completeness proof list of the document shared above.